# Gitlab redirect help page many times

Tags: gitlab

When we open our gitlab EE page help git.domain.com/help and click on any help link, the page is generate a link like this:

https://git.domain.com/help/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/16.7/ee/user/index.html.

instead

https://git.domain.com/help/16.7/ee/user/index.html
When we try to user the correct link, the same problem occurs

I have no idea how can I solve this. I guess that is a incorrect variable catching the version many times instead once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

The "Documentation pages URL:" should be filled by URL: "https://docs.gitlab.com" or in blank (to redirect to internal page help).

Thanks.